# Mapping controller endpoints to Spring JPA layer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, jpa

I've written this request mapping to access a ticket by it's id with the optional request parameters ticketType & ticketStatus :

```
@GetMapping(path = "/tickets/{ticketId}")
   @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<List<TicketResponse>> getTicketsById(@PathVariable("ticketId") final Long ticketId, @RequestParam("ticketType") final String ticketType, @RequestParam("ticketStatus") final String ticketStatus)
```

Currently the repository contains methods for returning based on either the ticketId or the ticketState :

```
    @Repository
    public interface TicketRepository extends JpaRepository<TicketEntity, Long> {

Stream<TicketEntity> findByTicketIdAndTicketState(@Param("ticketId") Long ticketId);

Stream<TicketEntity> findByTicketIdAndTicketState(@Param("ticketId") Long ticketId, @Param("ticketState") String ticketState);

    }
```

How should these endpoints be exposed at the controller layer ?

Currently the endpoint is:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/{ticketId}")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<List<TicketResponse>> getTicketsByTicketId(
            @PathVariable("productId") final Long ticketId, @RequestParam(name = "ticketState", required=false) final String ticketState) {

        final List<TicketResponse> ticketsByTicketId = ticketService.getTicketsByTicketId(ticketId);

        if(ticketsByTicketId.size() == 0){
            return ResponseEntity.ok("No tickets found");
        }
        else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(ticketsByTicketId);
        }

    }
```

Should I add a new endpoint? :

Or update the controller to select which JPA repository method to implement depending on the query ?:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/{ticketId}")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<List<TicketResponse>> getTicketsByTicketId(
            @PathVariable("productId") final Long ticketId, @RequestParam(name = "ticketState", required=false) final String ticketState) {

List<TicketResponse> tickets = null;

if(ticketState == null) {
        tickets = ticketService.getTicketsByTicketId(ticketId);
}
else{
tickets = ticketService.getTicketsByTicketIdAndTicketState(ticketId, ticketState);
}

        if(ticketsByTicketId.size() == 0){
            return ResponseEntity.ok("No tickets found");
        }
        else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(ticketsByTicketId);
        }

    }
```

The JPA repository will be extended further to filter based on many more parameters such as ticketType, ticketDescription . I just mention this as my controller logic will get very complicated if is required to check which parameter is null and the select the relevant JPA query.

Comment: Look up queryDSL. Personally I'd have a single mapping and pass a single filter Object containing all possible params. Then you can use queryDSL to build a query for your db based on set fields.

Comment: Also `@Param` is not needed in the repo

Comment: Also why are you returning Streams from a JPArepo?

Comment: @123 I return a stream in order to make use of the map function - the entities returned are mapped to another datatype.

Comment: Oh, I remember there being an issue when using them without `@Transactional`, where the connection hangs or something. May have been fixed now, but I probably wouldn't return them unless necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Spring Data JPA Specification this map filtering problem can be solved.
Complex queries can be build using the Criteria API depends on the filtering parameter.

[A good article about JPA Specification](https://sgitario.github.io/how-to-map-filters-from-rest-api-to/)