# Using JPA with multiple AND operations

Tags: java, spring, jpa, design-patterns, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a Spring app and defining various find methods on a repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TicketRepository extends JpaRepository<TicketEntity, Long> {

List<TicketEntity> findByTicketId(@Param("ticketId") Long ticketId);

List<TicketEntity> findByTicketIdAndState(@Param("ticketId") Long ticketId, @Param("state") String state);

List<TicketEntity> findByTicketIdAndStateAndFlagged(@Param("ticketId") Long ticketId, @Param("state") String state, @Param("flagged") String Flagged);

}
```

The problem is that I have 30 columns which can be optionally filtered on. This is will result in the repository methods becoming unwieldy:

```
List<TicketEntity> findByTicketIdAndStateAndFlaggedAndCol4AndCol5AndCol6AndCol7AndCol8AndCol9AndCol10AndCol11AndCol12AndCol13AndCol14AndCol15AndCol16AndCol17AndCol18AndCol19AndCol120....);
```

How should the JPA layer be designed to cater for this scenario ?

If I create an object with attributes:

```
public class SearchObject {
   private String attribute1; 
   //Getter and Setters
.
.
.
.
}
```

Can I pass `SearchObject` into a a find method and Spring JPA will determine which attributes to insert AND statements for depending on which attributes are Null - if the attribute is not null a corresponding AND is generated for that attribute.

Comment: Is the question  same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61041979/mapping-controller-endpoints-to-spring-jpa-layer ?

Comment: As I mentioned in the linked question, look up querydsl

Comment: @123 yes dsl query is also good solution JOOQ is very good option, its auto-generates model also

Comment: @Lemmy yes that I suggested him in his previous question

Answer (score 2):

1. Create filter object that will contain all optional columns e.g.:

@AllArgsConstructor
public class TicketFilter {

```
private final String col1;
private final Integer col2;

public Optional<String> getCol1() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(col1);
}

public Optional<Integer> getCol2() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(col2);
}
```

}

2. Extend your Respoitory with `JpaSpecificationExecutor`
3. Create specification class:

   public class TicketSpecification implements Specification {

   ```
   private final TicketFilter ticketFilter;

   public TicketSpecification(TicketFilter ticketFilter) {
       this.ticketFilter = ticketFilter;
   }

   @Override
   public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Ticket> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
       List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
       ticketFilter.getTitle().ifPresent(col1 -> predicates.add(getCol1Predicate(root, col1)));
       ticketFilter.getDescription().ifPresent(col2 -> predicates.add(getCol2Predicate(root, col2)));
       return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
   }
   ```

   private Predicate getCol1Predicate(Root root, String title) {
           return root.get("col1").in(col1);
       }

   }
4. Use your repository: `ticketRepository.findAll(specification);`

Comment: in line 'private Predicate getCol1Predicate(Root root, String title) { return root.get("col1").in(col1); }' how is col1 defined - compile time error is 'cannot resolve symbol col1'?

Comment: I think  'private Predicate getCol1Predicate(Root root, String title) { return root.get("col1").in(col1); }' should be defined as 'private Predicate getCol1Predicate(Root root, String col1) { return root.get("col1").in(col1); }' ?

Comment: It should be private Predicate getCol1Predicate(Root root, String col1) { return root.get("col1").in(col1); }

Comment: you need to replace col1 with valid field name from your entity

Answer (score 1):

Use Spring Data JPA Specification

**Detail Solution be patient**

First create a SpecificationCriteria class to define your criterias means filtering column as key and filtering value as value

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SpecificationCriteria {
  private String key;
  private Object value;
}
```

Then create SpecificationCriteriaBuilder to build your Criteria

```
@Service
public class SpecificationCriteriaBuilder {

  public List<SpecificationCriteria> buildCriterias(String name) {
    List<SpecificationCriteria> specificationCriterias = new ArrayList<SpecificationCriteria>();
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
      specificationCriterias
          .add(SpecificationCriteria.builder().key("name")
              .value(name).build());
    }
    // Here you can add other filter one by one 
    return specificationCriterias;
  }
}
```

Then create a SpecificationBuilder class to build your specifications.
You can build from the list of filter options(Criteria) to List of specification

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils;

@Service
public class SpecificationBuilder<T> {

  public Specification<T> buildSpecification(List<SpecificationCriteria> specificationCriterias) {
    if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(specificationCriterias)) {
      return null;
    }
    Specification<T> specification = getSpecification(specificationCriterias.get(0));
    for (int index = 1; index < specificationCriterias.size(); index++) {
      SpecificationCriteria specificationCriteria = specificationCriterias.get(index);
      specification =
          Specification.where(specification).and(getSpecification(specificationCriteria));
    }
    return specification;
  }

  public Specification<T> getSpecification(SpecificationCriteria specificationCriteria) {
    Specification<T> specification = new Specification<T>() {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 2089704018494438143L;
      @Override
      public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        return builder.equal(root.get(specificationCriteria.getKey()),
            specificationCriteria.getValue());
      }
    };
    return specification;
  }
}
```

In service first build criteria and then build specification using them. Then use specifications in repository call

```
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class UserService {

private final SpecificationCriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder;
private final SpecificationBuilder<User> specificationBuilder;
private final UserRepository userRepository;

public List<User> getAll(String name) {
    List<SpecificationCriteria> specificationCriterias =
        criteriaBuilder.buildCriterias(name); // here you can pass other parameter as function argument 
    Specification<User> specification =
        specificationBuilder.buildSpecification(specificationCriterias);
    List<User> users = userRepository.findAll(specification);// pass the specifications
    return users;
  }
```

Repository extend JpaSpecificationExecutor

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {

}
```