# Implementing RESTful GET endpoint with optional query parameters to fetch from DB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an HTTP GET endpoint which fetches from DB using Hibernate, the query parameters should be optional, if one is null then won't be used in the DB query.

The Endpoint:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/customer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResultRO getMenu(@RequestParam(required = false) String name, @RequestParam(required = false) Double minAge) {
        return customerService.getByParameters(new CutomerParameters(name,minPrice));
    }
```

The Hibernate DAO:

```
public List<Customer> getByParameters(CustomerParameters customerParameters) {
        Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery("select c from Customer c " +
                "where (:name is null or lower(c.name) like concat('%',lower(:name),'%')) " +
                "and (:minPrice is null or c.age >= :minAge)");
        query.setParameter("name",customerParameters.getName());
        query.setParameter("minAge",customerParameters.getMinAge());
        return query.list();
    }
```

Is it the cleanest and most correct way to do it, considering the parameters might change or removed over time? does Spring or Hibernate has already implemented something for this use case?

Comment: probably it's better to do this with Criteria API

Comment: You can use JPA Specifications [Ex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61245030/4207306)

Comment: @OlehKurpiak Isn't Criteria Deprecated?

Comment: @Eklavya it seems like more code than my simple usage of Hibernate Query, no?