# How to make a selection by the part of expression after "WHERE" using CriteriaApi or JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

How can I make a selection by the certain field using any possible expression using Criteria API or JPA?
For example I have a "price" field in my table.
So I want to implement an ability in UI to enter: "> 10 and < 50" and get all relevant results
">= 20" and get all relevant results
"!= 10" and get all relevant results
Or in text field:
"like %substring%"
And so on
Is it possible?

Comment: You can build your own library for JPA Specification Builder. I give an example of how to build it. Have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61062078/using-jpa-with-multiple-and-operations/61063853#61063853

Comment: Thanks for the example. I've implemented it about the same way, but I just wanted to avoid the trouble with parsing, and I thought that Criteria API provides some method to insert a part of query after WHERE

Answer (score 1):

Sure this is possible, depending on how complex you want these expressions allowed to be it might not be easy or not safe though.

You basically have two options:

1. you parse the expression and then use the parsed result to build your criteria.

   As [Abinash Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4207306/abinash-ghosh) noted: You can make that in the form of a `Specification` builder to interoperate nicely with Spring Data JPA.
2. **This is not recommended to use, I'm putting it mainly here so that I can note it as not safe** You can assemble a SQL or JPQL String and just use that as a query. It's simpler, because JPA will do the parsing for you. This will open up your application to SQL injection (or JPQL injection I guess). So don't use this.

Comment: Yes, I understand that this is not safe, but I just wanted to avoid the trouble with parsing, and I thought that Criteria API provides some method to insert a part of query after WHERE